# Query Fails whenever I want to insert

Tags: php, sql, insert

Each time i submit a form through the code below, i get "Query failed" but i can't seems to find the **error**.

> You have an **error** in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'order (pass, phone, fname, lname)
>   VALUES('test@yahoo.com','060606060606','James'' at line 1

Please someone help me.

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Include database connection details
require_once('../db/config.php');

//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false;

//Connect to mysql server
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
}

//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//Sanitize the POST values
$pass = clean($_POST['pass']);
$phone = clean($_POST['phone']);
$fname = clean($_POST['fname']);
$lname = clean($_POST['lname']);

//Create INSERT query
$qry = "INSERT INTO order (pass, phone, fname, lname) VALUES('$pass','$phone','$fname','$lname')";
$result = @mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    header("location: success.php");
    exit();
}else {
    die("Query failed");
}
?>
```

I also tried to check if the user inputs are empty and it was okay but it doesn't insert.

Comment: Change your `die` to `die("Query failed: " . mysql_error())` to see actual error.

Comment: Please avoid using **mysql**. It's deprecated. Use **mysqli_** or **PDO**.

Comment: See, What **Error** comes after updating this line `$result = @mysql_query($qry) or die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());`

Comment: @MarkusLaire, i get this error after applying your instruction. Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (pass, phone, fname, lname) VALUES('test@yahoo.com','060606060606','James'' at line 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The name 'order' is a MySQL reserved keyword.

Use backtick to enclose table name,

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO `order` (pass, phone, fname, lname) VALUES('$pass','$phone','$fname','$lname')";

                      ^ enlcose table name with backtick
```

**Backtick**

[image]

Comment: I think this has solved the problem but there is another error. Query failed: Field 'member_id' doesn't have a default value.

Comment: That's different problem. @NoreplyNoreply. Is `member_id` having primary_key and auto increment.

Comment: Yes it's a different problem now, i already marked your answer. Note: member_id has a primary key and auto increment too.

Comment: `member_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

Comment: Make it to NULL and check @NoreplyNoreply

Comment: This   `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, has solved it. Thanks.

Comment: *Glad That You Are Out Of Issue*. Keep Coding. @NoreplyNoreply

Answer (score 0):

And use "mysqli"

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO `order` (pass, phone, fname, lname) VALUES('$pass','$phone','$fname','$lname')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
```

Comment: Okay. I will do that. Thanks